# How to grep last two characters after a number in unix shell scripting

Tags: linux, unix

I am using below in .txt file for my script

```
abc20cb1a
abc20cb1aa
abc20cb1b
abc20cb1bb
```

I want to do a particular task for `aa` and `bb` and another particular task for `a` and `b`. To be more precise and clear, the task which I am doing for lines ending in `aa` and `bb` should not work for lines ending in `a` and `b`, and similarly the task which I am doing for endings `a` and `b` should not work for `aa` and `bb` endings.

For example:

- For `aa` and `bb` side I want to go to one directory.
- For `a` and `b` side I want to to multiple directories.

How can I do that?

Comment: What are you using for these scripts? bash?

Comment: yes i am using bash

Answer (score 1):

Your question shows your text file as "one line".  I'm guessing that's a mistake?

Regular expressions will dig you out of this hole.

You could parse a multiline file like so:

```
$ cat example.txt
abc20cb1a
abc20cb1aa
abc20cb1b
abc20cb1bb

$ while read LINE; do
     echo "$LINE" | egrep '[^ab][ab]{2}$' > /dev/null
     if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         # double letter
         echo "Double: $LINE"
     else
         # single letter
         echo "Single: $LINE"
     fi
  done < example.txt
```